# Unable to set iTotalRecords and iTotalDisplayRecords in datatable

Tags: java, jquery, grails, groovy, datatables

The datatable is showing the aaData values but the pagination is wrong.

```
$("#tableData").DataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bsort":true,
    "orderMulti":true,
    "sAjaxSource":"datalist",
    "sAjaxDataProp":  function ( json ) {
        var msgObj = JSON.parse(json);
        console.log(msgObj)
        return msgObj.aaData;
    },
    "aoColumns": [
        { "data": "scheduleId" },
        { "data": "startTime" },
        { "data": "endTime" },
        { "data": "selectFlag" }
    ]
});
```

This is the json data:

```
{"iTotalRecords":7,"iTotalDisplayRecords":7,"aaData":
  [
    {"scheduleId":1,"startTime":"02:00","endTime":"04:00","selectFlag":false},
    {"scheduleId":2,"startTime":"02:00","endTime":"04:00","selectFlag":false},
    {"scheduleId":3,"startTime":"02:00","endTime":"04:00","selectFlag":false},
    {"scheduleId":4,"startTime":"02:00","endTime":"04:00","selectFlag":false},
    {"scheduleId":5,"startTime":"02:00","endTime":"04:00","selectFlag":false},
    {"scheduleId":6,"startTime":"02:00","endTime":"04:00","selectFlag":false},
    {"scheduleId":7,"startTime":"03:00","endTime":"04:00","selectFlag":false}
]}
```

Below I have attached the image of datatable.

[image: Datatable]

Can you please point out the mistake I have made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `sAjaxDataProp` option, it's not needed. Also your JSON response is missing `sEcho` parameter, which is *unaltered copy of `sEcho` sent from the client side*.

See [Example JSON return](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) for more details.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/64Lmwhgc/1/) for code and demonstration. Please note that the example will not sort/filter/paginate correctly because there is no server-side script available.

Comment: i did gave sEcho value and removed sAjaxDataProp but this time it gave the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)" in the browser console.

Comment: @Padma, added example to demonstrate the solution.